# Cannot mention person in Adaptive Card using Teams PowerShell Module

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have registered an [Incoming Messages Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook#:%7E:text=Incoming%20Webhook%20allows%20any%20external,a%20message%20in%20card%20format.) in one of my Teams channels.
I am using [Microsoft Teams PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/teams/?view=teams-ps) to create an adaptive card and send it to a channel:

```
$SimpleCard = @{
    type = "message";
    attachments = @(@{
        contentType  = 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive';
        contentUrl = $null;
        content = @{
            '$schema' = 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json';
            type = 'AdaptiveCard';
            version = '1.2';
            body = @(@{
                type = 'TextBlock';
                text = "Hello <at>andrea.tino@mycompany.com</at>";
            })
        }
    });
    msteams = @{
        entities = @(@{
            type = 'mention';
            text = "<at>andrea.tino@mycompany.com</at>";
            mentioned = @{
                id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
                name = 'Andrea Tino';
            }
        })
    }
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method post
                  -ContentType 'Application/Json'
                  -Body ($SimpleCard | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10)
                  -Uri "https://myorg.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/IncomingWebhook/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

The card is correctly sent but the mention is not correctly rendered.

### Wrong ID?

It is worth mentioning that [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#sample-adaptive-card-with-a-mention) makes explicit reference to a type of User ID:

```
{
  "type": "mention",
  "text": "<at>John Doe</at>",
  "mentioned": {
    "id": "29:123124124124",
    "name": "John Doe"
  }
}
```

You can see that the ID in the example is: `"id": "29:123124124124"` while mine is a GUID. I retrieved that User ID by means of [`Get-TeamUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/get-teamuser?view=teams-ps).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mention in adaptive card is supported only in context of bot and the available ways to get id are listed in the document - [mention-support-within-adaptive-cards-v12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#mention-support-within-adaptive-cards-v12)

Concerned team is working to support user mention using AAD Object Id and UPN(use Graph API) in Incoming Webhook.

Answer (score 0):

ID and Name can be fetched from the activity as follows

```
from: {
id: '29:15fREhoUuf6vVCOuaJYVH-AB6QXXX',
name: 'MOD Administrator',
aadObjectId: 'XXXX'
}
```

Giving a reference that will help - [mention-support-within-adaptive-cards-v12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#mention-support-within-adaptive-cards-v12)

Comment: I do not get how you retrieve ID and name. You mention you can retrieve them from the activity. What activity? If you see my code, how can I get that piece of code you show?

Comment: Also the doc you refer to does not tell me how to retrieve that ID, it tells how to mention... the it has a section about how to retrieve the ID but that is not useful for the API I am using

Comment: Please note that you can add @mentions within an Adaptive Card body for bots and messaging extension responses. The userId is unique to your bot ID and a particular user. 
As per the doc, the ID mentioned can be retrieved  from the bot context.

Comment: I do not have a Bot context. I am using just powershell commands by calling the REST API and just providing a PAT. How do I retrieve that info when I am using Powershell?